# Spring injection question

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a static class `ResourceFetcher` with a static method `fetchResource(String reference)`. I want to inject the resource returned by it into another class `JobRunner`. Can anyone specify the cleanest way of doing this?

I do not want to pass `ResourceFetcher` into `JobRunner`. In fact, I have an `enum` with set of keys, and I need to pass a map of key-value pairs into `JobRunner` with values obtained by invoking `fetchResource`.

Onething I want to clarify is that `ResourceFetcher` class' `fetchResource` returns an object of type `String`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
<bean id="resource" class="com.x.y.ResourceFetcher" factory-method="fetchResource">
   <constructor-arg value="someReference"/>
</bean>
```

You can then inject `resource` into your `JobRunner` bean.

Comment: Great. This is what I anticipated too. What if object returned by factory-method is not of type class ResourceFetcher?

Comment: @kuriouskat: The bean type will be whatever is returned by the method, the type of `ResourceFetcher` is irrelevant to the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the `fetchResource` method is static on ResourceFetcher, why can't JobRunner simply refer to it?  I don't see the need to inject ResourceFetcher.

Comment: How would this be generic if ResourceFetcher if I want to transform 10 sql files in classpath into sql strings? To be precise, I had a static map as following in my JobRunner - Map<String, String> queryTempl where each values where sql queries fetched from ResourceFetcher as String. I was wondering if this was a right way to go about things.